# Is it possible to selectively inherit interface from another

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to selectively inherit interface from another

See examples below

```
interface A { 
id: string
name: string
gender:string
address: string []
}

interface B { 
id: string
name: string
gender:string
address: number []
}
```

The only difference is the attribute **address** , one is string [] and another one is number []

Can I do this ?

```
interface B extend A { 
address: number []
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well no you can't, you will get an error:

```
Interface 'B' incorrectly extends interface 'A'.
  Types of property 'address' are incompatible.
    Type 'number[]' is not assignable to type 'string[]'.
      Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

But what you can do is inherit all the fields except `address` using [`Omit`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys)

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN7IFDL84AEwC5kBnMKUAcwG5d8Q4BbCUiqkOhvaiEQtHaUa9fMjiFCUCGTLDO1ANoBdegF9s2UJFiIUAIWQQAHpAFk0mHOMnTZ85CACuzAEbRkqjVp3R4SMgGAEzGZvyElgDyzMBgADyoADQARHYycikAfJg8ElIZji7u0N7YmtgIAPYgFAS1YHAgSKQhyAC8ueJEpCkAjClJeUysvQBiVVWDeXwCQsgpzHAANhDTtgUOpEp9ScjBewDMKuW0QA)

```
interface A { 
    id: string;
    name: string;
    gender: string;
    address: string[];
}

// This doesn't work
/*
interface B extends A { 
    address: number[];
}
*/

// This does
interface B2 extends Omit<A,"address"> {
    address: number[];
}

const myInstance: B2 = {
    id: "1",
    name: "Foo",
    gender: "male",
    address: [1, 2, 3]
};
```

---

Another valid solution would be to have a generic interface.

```
interface X<T = number | string> { 
    id: string;
    name: string;
    gender: string;
    address: T[];
}

interface A extends X<string> { 
}

interface B extends X<number> { 
}

const instance: B = {
    id: "1",
    name: "Foo",
    gender: "male",
    address: [1, 2, 3]
};
```

Answer (score 2):

The [`Omit`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys) is very handy here. For interfaces omit the `address` property and redefine it in the new interface.

```
interface A {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  gender: string;
  address: string[];
}

interface B extends Omit<A, "address"> {
  address: number[];
}
```

If you want to use types instead of interfaces you can use an [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types).

```
type A = {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  gender: string;
  address: string[];
};

type B = Omit<A, "address"> & {address: number[]};
```